# How to do async with sync methods properly?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

here is my problem:

i have two TCP-Connections. The first one controls only one machine (M-A) and when it starts the process nothing else is possible to do until it finishes its work. The second connections controls five machines (M-B) which can do their work completely independent from each other or any other process.

For the application: I have a database alert which serves as my EventHandler for Insertion on a specific table. The EventHandler calls a method for getting the inserted Data. Based on the Data i get i want to start either one or two or three or all M-Bs or the M-A.

Since each M-B can start the next job after completion i wanted to run them asynchronously and the M-A synchronously.

Its the first time for me writing asynchronous, so Methods i would like to ask for help to direct me into the right way.

```
public class OracleAlertListener 
{
   public OracleAlertListener()
   {
      //Initialize the alerter
   }

   private async void Alert_OnAlert(object sender, OracleAlerterAlertEventArgs e)
   {
      Qm.Getjobs();
   }
}

public class QueueManager
{
    public void GetJobs(int jnum)
    {
        var sql = @"select * from table ...";

        /*
            Get the data into "job". "job" = a single row with command
         */

        DoWork(job);
    }

    public async void DoWork(DataRow job)
    {
        if (job["ACTION"].Equals("E"))
        {
            Task mbCommand = ProcessMBAsync(job);
            await mbCommand;
        }
        else
        {
            var result = ProcessMACommand(job);
        }
    }
    private async Task<DataRow> ProcessMBAsync(DataRow job)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // Do some Work
        });
    }

    private Boolean ProcessMACommand(DataRow job)
    {
        // Do some work
    }
}
```

Everything i read about asynchronous Programming told me not to use void async methods. When i start my DoWork(job) i don't really need the result of it (also not from GetJobs(int jnum)) rather i need it from the methods ProcessMBAsync and ProcessMACommand.

In ProcessMBAsync i want to know which of the five M-B finished and is ready to start a new job, that's why i return a DataRow to get the information of the job done.

In ProcessMACommand i just want to know if the job was successfull.

So my Question is: How would be the correct way to construct this procedure?

EDIT: I mean how to construct this procedure, so that i can avoid an async void Method. Run the jobs for M-B asynchrounsly and afterwards know which one finished (since the M-A is synchron and i will always know when it finishes the job).

The AlertListener is rather obsolet (it isn't necessary, just convenient) and i don't want to build this procedure focusing on this Eventhandler.

Thanks for your advices.

Btw: i read these articels :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/0ba7625050f975f8a7df1df57c80ad08da250541/AsyncGuidance.md and several other threads on stackoverflow.com

Comment: If you just need to synchronize when a task is done across threads, then use something like [`AutoResetEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.autoresetevent?view=netframework-4.8), based on [`EventWaitHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.eventwaithandle?view=netframework-4.8). See also [`Mutex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: In case a call to `ProcessMBAsync` throws an exception, what would you like to happen? 1) Your program should crash with an unhandled exception. 2) The exception should be silently swallowed, unknowingly to you. 3) You want to be informed and properly handle the exception.

Comment: In this case i would like to be informed and handle the exception.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this question - it's not really clear to me what problem you're trying to solve. If you just want to avoid `async void` in `DoWork` then you need to make both `DoWork` and `GetJobs` async, make them return `Task` and await them.

Comment: I'm asking for advice. I would like to know if this is the right way for implementing asynchronous Methods. Is there a possibility that i run into deadlocks? Did i forget something? Does it make sense to make `DoWork` and `GetJobs` async since i don't need a feedback from these methods but rather from ProcessMBAsync and ProcessMACommand?

Comment: It sounds like you're a bit confused about what `async` actually is. It's not about whether or not you get feedback - you will generally wait for all async methods to complete - it's about whether the underlying operation blocks the main thread, or whether you release that thread for some other operation while non-blocking work completes. If a method is async, so should be all of the methods calling it, right up to the top of the stack. Otherwise you generally gain nothing by making a method async in the first place.